# How to cast object of type 'X.PagedList.StaticPagedList` to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I try to cast a `X.PagedList.StaticPagedList` to an `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable` I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   'X.PagedList.StaticPagedList'`(CbWebApp.DTOs.UsuarioDTO)` to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable'`(CbWebApp.DTOs.UsuarioDTO)`.

My current approach:

```
int pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1;
int pageSize = 5;
int totalCount = 0;

IPagedList<UsuarioDTO> pageList;
UsuarioViewModel listaUsuario = new UsuarioViewModel();

if (IdDoPerfilDoUsuario == null | IdDoPerfilDoUsuario == 0 | IdDoPerfilDoUsuario == 123)
{
    Tuple<int, IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>> callMethod = await UsuarioService.UsuarioServiceGetAllAsync();

    totalCount = callMethod.Item1;

    pageList = new StaticPagedList<UsuarioDTO>((IEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>)callMethod.Item2, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalCount);

    // The problem of casting is here
    listaUsuario.Usuarios = (IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>)pageList;
}
```

My ViewModel class:

```
public class UsuarioViewModel
{
    public IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `listaUsuario.Usuarios = callMethod.Item2;`?

Comment: bkoz i am using the X.PagedList component. I will have to cast it anyway from my DTO to ViewModel.

Comment: Is there any reason you define a ViewModel as `IAsyncEnumerable`? `IAsyncEnumerable` need to call await to check the result. I suggest you try replace `IAsyncEnumerable` with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @TaoZhou yes, it is! Cause my UsuarioDTO recieves IAsyncEnumerable from my service tier. It´s almost a DDD approach i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems IPagedList supports IEnumerable according to code.
( https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs )
I think this is part of standard for now.

Then you should be able to perform something similar:

```
using System.Linq;

/*...*/

List<???> lst = pageList.ToList();
```

For example there ( https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/StaticPagedList/-/php-staticpagedlist-class-examples.html#0xacb00bf3a6a951296f72a6d945cc395a5b56a0f019d2b045585be469e0fe3235-36,,65, ) is some use of it.

If you will be unsuccessfull by double conversion with Linq, then your last way is foreach cycle and fill target variable manually.

There is also Convert class in C# ( https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.7.2 ) but thats not so good for using with complex types.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I appreciate your awnser and i'll give a try asap and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to define the `IAsyncEnumerable` from service tier. But, you should not convert between `IEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>` and `IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>` implicit. And you should not define ViewModel with `IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>`. For `IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>`, you need to call `ToEnumerable()` to get the result.

Try to define ViewModel with `IEnumerable`.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }     
}
```

`pageList` is `IEnumerable<UserDTO>`, you could set its value directly like:

```
listaUsuario.Users = pageList;
```

If you got error related with converting `IAsyncEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>` to `IEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>` at this line `pageList = new StaticPagedList<UsuarioDTO>((IEnumerable<UsuarioDTO>)callMethod.Item2, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalCount);`.

Try

```
pageList = new StaticPagedList<UserDTO>(callMethod.Item2.ToEnumerable(), pageIndex + 1, pageSize, totalCount);
```